# How to define spool file with substitution variable

Tags: plsql

I'm using Oracle sql plus to execute a script PL/SQL.
Here’s my script:

```
set serveroutput on
spool "Svincoli_giornalieri.csv"
declare
    v_id_rapporto number(20);

begin

    v_id_rapporto := &id_rapporto;
    select id_rapporto into v_id_rapporto from  tb_ag_rapporti where   id_rapporto = v_id_rapporto;

    for c in (
            select r.intestazione,vn.id_rapporto,vn.IMPORTO_SVINCOLABILE,vn.IMPORTO_ORIG,svn.ID_OP_VNC,svn.importo,svn.DATA_INS,svn.STATO_CSE ,svn.DATA_ESECUZIONE
            from tb_op_vnc vn, TB_OP_SVN svn, tb_ag_rapporti r
            where vn.ID_OP_VNC=svn.ID_OP_VNC
            and r.id_rapporto =vn.id_rapporto
            and svn.DATA_INS>trunc(sysdate)
            )
 loop

        dbms_output.put_line( c.intestazione||' idr: '||c.id_rapporto||'  ID_Vincolo:'||c.ID_OP_VNC||' '||c.stato_cse||'  Data Esec: '||c.DATA_ESECUZIONE||'  Importo orig:'||c.IMPORTO_ORIG||' Svincolo Residuo:'||c.IMPORTO_SVINCOLABILE||'  Importo Svincolato:'||c.importo);


    end loop;
    end;
    /
    spool off
```

I want to pass the output in a spool file using the substitution variable but when I launch my script I get this error:

```
ERRORE alla riga 6:
ORA-06550: riga 6, colonna 26:
PLS-00103: Trovato il simbolo "OFF" anziche uno dei seguenti:
. ( * @ %
& = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<un esponente (**)> <> o != o ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
Il simbolo "." e stato sostituito per permettere a "OFF" di continuare.
```

I can’t figure out how to solve this problem.  Could someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically specify a spool file in SQL*Plus you migt want to use something like:

```
column filename new_val filename
select 'file_' || to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd' ) filename from dual;
spool &filename
```

Unfortunately I do not understand how this relates to the (Italian) error message you also posted.

If you could show the complete output including the line numbers and an english error text this might be better to understand.
Is the error in the line with "spool off" and did you try to add a blank line before the spool off?

Comment: @giancarlo Could you then please mark my answer as solution.

Comment: I was using the same variable name v_id_rapporto := &id_rapporto, changing the name now everything is working.